# Is there a way to download/clone multiple github repositories using python by using a loop

Tags: python-3.x, git, github, clone

I want to clone multiple github repositories on my local machine. I am using python and I ran the github clone command:
`!git clone rep_name`
here rep_name is a variable that has the link.
I want to do this because I want to repeat this for multiple github repositories. I used the for loop as follows:

```
  for i in range(len(repo_list)):
    print("Downloaing repository " + i)
    !git clone 'https://github.com/' + repo_list[i]
```

Comment: Why python and not a shell script? `for repo in repos...; do git clone "https://github.com/$repo"; done`

Comment: Doesn't matter which language you use. Just google how to run a command line script in python. Easy alternatives would be Powershell, bash or shell like mentioned already. The advantage there is, that they are pre-installed on most OS and python is not.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :

```
import os

repo_list = []
# You can also write in repo list the username of the repo owner and remove it from the function
for repo in repo_list:
    os.system("git clone https://github.com/USERNAME_OF_REPO_OWNER/" + repo + ".git")
```